# Iteratively displaying a set of images, showing only 1 at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Is there a way to loop through a set number of images, displaying each one in turn (only 1 at a time, each new one in the same place as the previous one)? How would I accomplish this?

I managed to create this kind of effect with jQuery where I'd fadeIn and fadeOut each image. Is there a way to do this with JavaScript, without the additional library?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript...

Comment: Anything that you can do in jquery can be done in plain javascript.

Comment: Look at the source code of jQuery to see how it does `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

Comment: You would have to look at how jQuery does its animations; though, CSS3 has some funky stuff you can use as well :)

Comment: Just curious—why the constraint that you can't use jQuery?

Comment: @nbrooks No constraint, just now starting trying to learn JavaScript (among other languages) rather than just relying on jQuery. I never actually committed to learning how to how to code JS originally, just relied on using haphazard bits of jQuery to create the desired effects without really understanding what was going on.

Comment: There are a lot of variables. How are the image urls pulled? What does your markup look like? etc... jQuery is nice to smooth over these variables, but it definitely can be done using vanilla JS. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FJv4d/

Comment: @eidsonator That is actually backwards. jQuery adds features to javascript. Your statement should read "Anything that you can do in plain javascript can be done in jQuery"

Comment: @CodyGuldner jquery is written in javaxcript, it doesn't add anything, it just adds functions to make things easier to accomplish.

Comment: @Cody false. jQuery is simply a library which provides some useful functions (*written in JavaScript*) which save you from having to rewrite them frequently in 'plain JavaScript'. Anything that you can do in jQuery can be done without using the library, since the library implements the methods in JS in the first place.

Comment: @eidsonator I understand that. But you can't navigate the DOM in javascript using `$` like you can in jQuery

Comment: @Cody `$` is a variable like any other variable, and is simply the name jQuery uses to represent their object, which is a plain old JavaScript object. You *can* navigate the DOM using JS, which is in fact how jQuery does it, it's just easier to do so with the help of the pre-defined jQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to do what you say.

NOTE: It will stop on the last image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
var imagePaths = ["images/slide1.jpg", "images/slide2.jpg", "images/slide3.jpg"];
var showCanvas = null;
var showCanvasCtx = null;
var img = document.createElement("img");
var currentImage = 0;
var revealTimer;
var timeoutVariable = 3000;

window.onload = function () {
  showCanvas = document.getElementById('SlideShowCanvas');
  showCanvasCtx = showCanvas.getContext('2d');
  img.setAttribute('width', '560');
  img.setAttribute('height', '343');
  switchImage();
  setInterval(switchImage, timeoutVariable);
}

function switchImage() {
// Loop once
if (currentImage >= imagePaths.length) {
  clearInterval(revealTimer);
  clearTimeout(timeoutVariable);
} else {
  img.setAttribute('src', imagePaths[currentImage++]);
  showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
  revealTimer = setInterval(revealImage, 100);
}

function revealImage() {
  showCanvasCtx.save();
  showCanvasCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 560, 343);
  showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha += 0.1;
  if (showCanvasCtx.globalAlpha > 1.0)
  clearInterval(revealTimer);
  showCanvasCtx.restore();
}
// -->
</script>
```

## Ooops

forgot to add the html

```
<canvas id="SlideShowCanvas" style="width: 560px; height: 343px;" width="560px" height="343px">
  <div style="width: 560px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height: 343px; border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;">
    <span style="width: 560px; height: 343px;">
      <br /><br />Your browser does not support<br />the html5 canvas object!<br /><br /><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/ie">Click Here To Download Microsoft's</a><br />Feature Rich Internet Explorer Web Browser<br />
    </span>
  </div>
</canvas>
```